# We need help with joining LAN worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I join someone else's LAN world on Minecraft? My brother and I are trying to join each others worlds on it and are having trouble.

Comment: You can't. You need a multiplayer server to play together

Comment: Do you know what "single player" means?

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Are you and your brother on the same network? What is the "trouble" that you are having? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can only join a LAN world if the host is on the same network (WiFi) as you. The definition of LAN is "Local Area Network" which basically means a network near you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [set up the server correctly](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server), you should be able to connect to it without any issues assuming you are on the same LAN (Local Area Network).

If you are not on the same network then trying to connect as though you are on a LAN will not work. The best option is to create a regular server that is accessible over the internet.

But if you can't figure that out or if you really insist on connecting to a LAN only server, then you may want to try Hamachi. This will simulate being on a LAN over the internet. There is a tutorial for it specifically for Minecraft even.
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hamachi_connection_LAN

Answer (score -4):

1) Stay on the same wifi/LAN network and have one of you open the world and the other go to multiplayer for multiplayer. It didnt work for me, so I tried this:

As my PC is strong, I downloaded the [server.jar here](https://mcversions.net).
Then I ran the server. As long as you go on the same LAN network, just click add server and type "localhost" in the IP address area.

For more info, you may watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqaQqrbccRM). I did not make it.

Comment: This isn't the answer for this question.

Comment: So, what about the other guy? Does he type `localhost` too and connect to his non-existent server that's not the other person's LAN server? :P